# What is the purpose of closing a branch

Tags: mercurial, branch

[image]

I was wondering, what is the purpose of closing a branch. As for `issue-1` branch, I had already close. But

- I still can see `issue1-1` in my revision graph
- I still can switch to branch `issue1-1`, and continue to commit.

So, what is the whole point of closing a branch?

Comment: Control-question: Do you *want* to see "issue-1" in the history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches

It is informational so that `hg branches` will show that these branches are closed. And `hg heads --active` will not display any heads that are marked closed.

In a long run, number of branches can be considerable and can add to informational noise. This is a good way to prune some of those noise.

Comment: Suggesting someone prune branches to fix UI clutter is like suggesting someone throw away their family photos to make room in their closet.  We're talking about version control, and discarding history shouldn't be considered an option.

Comment: Ry4an, take a read of the link.  I think you are just going by the somewhat misleading name.  It actually discusses closing branches as well as the negatives of pruning.  Like most of the Hg documentation, it's fairly good about telling you where the dragons are.

Comment: @Ry4an: your analogy is flawed. Nothing is "thrown away", no history is discarded. Closing a branch only adds a little metadata to it to mark it as closed.

Comment: Wim, my analogy was talking about 'pruning branches' as suggested in pyfunc's answer, which is discarding history using cloning or the strip command.  Merely closing branches certainly isn't destructive, is good practice, and is what the questioner was already doing.

Comment: @pyfunc closing is what he was already doing, he just asked what effect it was having.  The link mentions closing and then two destructive methods.  I'm glad to hear you weren't suggesting them, but it's not clear from your answer.

Comment: @Ry4an : It is possible that it is not clear. After All, I am trying to communicate and I can fail at that. I thought, I communicated it well that you can reduce informational noise. Say using hg heads --active, branches marked as close will not show up. I thought, I summed up the effect through this piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why named branches probably aren't the right choice for per-feature and per-issue branches -- you can hide them but you can't eliminate them.  Consider reserving named branches for long-lived concepts like 'stable', 'experimental', etc.  For per-issue and per-feature branching either anonymous branches, clone branches, or bookmarks are better solutions.  They're all described wonderfully here:
[A Guide to Branching In Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/).

Comment: If you ever plan to make your changes available to someone else without usurping their main branch, I have to suggest that making a named branch first is critical.  Once you've made changes on a default branch, nobody else can receive it without it taking over their main branch.  You can, of course, make another clone to receive it, but that's not possible in some scenarios like sharing through a central repo.  Named branches are the safest and most general way to avoid such an issue.  AFAIK, bookmarks aren't sufficient because they are strictly local.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "taking over the main branch".  People pull and then 'update' to whichever head they want, and if they choose not to update they stay where they were.  Bookmarks have been pushable/pullable since version 1.6 as mentioned in the document to which I linked.  I've used mercurial extensively for years in large-collaboration environments without ever needing named branches, and certainly not for short-term development arcs like features and fixes.

Comment: Interesting news on the bookmarks, that makes them more interesting.  I'll have to check out what else has changed in that regard, as I like the fact that they don't persist when you're done with them.  I'll have to see what support is provided for them in our CI system.  My concern with multiple anonymous branches is that a) a third party has no idea which is which and b) CI systems are unable to distinguish between the heads and will behave in a seemingly non-deterministic way until you figure out that it's seeing multiple heads and choosing which to build by selecting the tip.  That's all.

Comment: bookmarks present as tags, so it's likely your CI system can check them out for building just fine.